# urn problem with replacement drawing only two different numbers in 4 tuple

Tags: probability

I have an urn with 7 distinct balls which have the number 1 - 7 written on each.
I draw 4 times with replacement and want to find the probability of having only two distinct numbers in each drawn 4 tuple.

I came up with arranging my result space as $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ but exactly one time for $0 \leq i < j \leq 4 $a_i ≠ a_j$ within each tuple.

for example for $a_1 = 1$ this would be the following outcome: $(1,2,2,2),...,(1,1,1,2),(1,3,3,3),...,(1,1,1,3),...,(1,1,1,7)$ for every possible number $a_4 \in \{2,...,7\}$

This would lead to having $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 3$ outcomes. $7$ since every number 1 to 7 can be chosen as $a_1$, 6 since I can choose 6 remaining numbers as $a_4$ and sample them on 3 different positions of $j$ since I only have 3 place to choose $j$.

For the sample space I would choose having $7^4$ possibilities since I choose with replacement and have 7 to choose for every pick. This would lead to a probability of $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 3 \over 7^4$

I am actually not sure if this is correct and if there might be a more general way to approach this maybe even for different numbers.

Comment: You don't seem to count cases like $1122$ where two numbers are each drawn twice.  Why is that?

Comment: I actually wanted to count them I just didnt put it into the example. I think the case 1122 should be within choosing three different position for j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this too hard.  There are $\binom72$ choices for the two numbers that appear.  Having chosen them, there are $2^4$ ways to make $4$ choices from them, but we have to exclude the two cases where we choose the same number four times.  That gives $$14\binom72=7\cdot7\cdot6$$ choices, and a probability of $$\frac6{49}$$

Comment: thank you quite clear, I kind of felt that I must be missing some point.

Comment: $2^4 - 2$ for excluding two cases